# Initialising UIView in main thread from a background thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async, background-thread

In a global, async closure, I'd like to initialise a `UIView` on the main thread. I thought this code would possibly do it, but I get an Analyser warning:

> `UIView.init(frame:)` must by used from the main thread only.

```
let view: UIView = { // Line with the warning
      DispatchQueue.main.sync {
          return UIView()
      }
}()
```

Comment: What's the purpose of doing such a thing? could you please mention what's your general goal?

Comment: I'm generating a PDF from some xibs. I need a container for them. This is the only line that gives an warning.

Comment: I think this is odd! Are you tried without `DispatchQueue.main.sync`? Why do you need this?

Comment: I haven't because that would still be on the global queue and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @JoshParadroid Try to use `async` instead

Comment: I have code later that depends upon the contents of view. Wouldn't async cause that value to be possibly unset at that point in time?

Comment: I'd like to know what the down-vote was for. I'm not disputing it, I'm just interested.

Comment: @JoshParadroid You're right! Honestly. It's not me. Good luck mate!

Comment: @Mannopson Sorry — I didn't mean to sound accusatory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll be helpful if u post more of the code so we could understand the context better.
Anyway, this should work nicely:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    private var customView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCustomView()
    }

    private func setupCustomView() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            /*
             1. Do some preperation / data init' on background thread.
             2. When ready, perform UI dependent initialization on main thread.
             */
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                /* Initialize `customView` on the main queue. for example: */
                self.customView = UIView()
                self.view.addSubview(self.customView)
                self.customView.backgroundColor = .red
                self.customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Using a completion handler would be cleaner. Technically, I would recommend split it into two functions anyway.

Comment: @Sulthan, I agree. My code wasn't by 'best practice' standards but it should be executed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

You can keep using your own implementation, without `DispatchQueue.main.sync`

```
let view: UIView = { 
      return UIView()
}()
```

However you can go back to the main thread anytime:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.view.addSubview(view) 
}
```

Use the `.async`, it's gives you an independent thread